# realtime firebase database read data from request

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

So I'm have 3 collections

1- cases

3- owner (inside cases collection)

2- invitations

in normal senario when user add invitation I check if user that tray this action is owner or not by , take `caseId` from `newDate` and uid from `auth.uid` and compare these data by exist in `cases collection`

but it's always give me permission denied.

```
 // Any one have cases
 "cases":{ 
   ".write" : "auth.uid != null"

  // Store id of owner only when case created first time
   "owner"  : {
     ".write": "!data.exists()"
   }
 }

//only Owner of case can add invitations
 "invitations":{
   ".write" :"root.child('cases').child(newData.child('caseId').val()).child('owner').child(auth.uid).exists()",
 },
```

the data that I'm sending to `invitations` collection  are

```
Invitation(
  endAt: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 1)),
  id: invitationId,
  caseId: caseId,
);
```

**Edit**
When I try replace `newData.child('caseId').val()` with caseId value as static string value , it's working !!

Comment: Security rules don't do anything on their only. Only once you run code against them, do they become active. Please edit your question to show the [minimal code that reproduces the problem you have with these rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), what you expect that code to do, and what happens instead.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have update my question, I hope I have explained well this time

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen. I was wrong due to I used `newDate` in parent not child that I will write so i put my rules under `"$invitationId"` and its' working, so am I correct about that , I can use `newDate` only inside child that will create not in his parent ?

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem Mahmoud! 

Answer (score 0):

For whom faced this issue , I was wrong due to I used `newDate` in parent not child that I will write so i put my rules under `"$invitationId"` and its' working.

```
 //only Owner of case can add invitations
     "invitations":{
       "$invitationId":{
        ".write" :"root.child('cases').child(newData.child('caseId').val()).child('owner').child(auth.uid).exists()",
       }
     },
```